# Reexport module under different name

Tags: rust

i want to write a cross plattform library and therefore i have written the following code

```
pub mod common;
#[cfg(target_os = "Linux")]
pub mod process_linux;

#[cfg(target_os = "Windows")]
pub mod process_windows;
```

But now i want to reexport the modules both under the name process.
Is this easily possible ? I think i may have to read more about modules and namespaces in the future, i tried the following:

```
pub mod process {
    #[cfg(target_os = "Linux")]
    pub use process_linux::*;

    #[cfg(target_os = "Windows")]
    pub use process_windows::*;
}
```

But it is still not working like i want, maybe someone has the answer.

Edit:
For example i want to be able to run the same code on different machines like, but at the moment the imports are not working, i must use process_linux instead:

```
// doesnt work
use tryolib::process::*;
// works
use tryolib::process_linux::*;
```

Ok so now i tried:

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "Linux")]
mod process_linux;

#[cfg(target_os = "Windows")]
mod process_windows;

#[cfg(target_os = "Linux")]
pub use process_linux as process;

#[cfg(target_os = "Windows")]
pub use process_windows as process;
```

Comment: Sorry, but with the recent edit it is still unclear what the problem is. Does that not compile? It also not exactly a [mre], as we are unable to reproduce this ourselves. You may also be interested in knowing the full syntax for [use statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/use-declarations.html): you _can_ do `use somecrate::module_name as another_name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a typo, OS must be in lowrcase (as [reference states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_os)). The following code works ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=612743fc999ffc23bdc5447cd1b72b3c)):

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
pub mod process_linux {
    pub type T = ();
}

#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
use process_linux as process;

fn main() {
    let _: process::T = ();
}
```